# How to optimize the cose-bilkent layout with lots of nodes and edges like a mess

Tags: layout, cytoscape.js

With few elements, I got a reasonable graph with `cose-bilkent` layout. But in my real scenario, I put lots of nodes and edges into graph and got a mess. I tried to ajust the options of `cose-bilkent`, but still not got a satisfactory layout.

Could expert use my data to layout a more reasonable graph?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),

    ready: function() {
      this.layout({
        name: "cose-bilkent"
      }).run();
    },

    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          'content': 'data(id)',
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'text-halign': 'center',
          'background-color': 'blue',
          'color':'red',
          'width':'10px', 
    'height':'10px'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: ":parent",
        style: {
          "background-opacity": 0.333
        }
      },

      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          width: 3,
          "line-color": "#ad1a66"
        }
      }
    ],

    elements: [{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"n_0"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"202","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"240","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"121","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"89","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"193","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"88","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"328","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"65","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"80","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"66","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"120","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"1","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"351","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"94","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"299","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"17","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"324","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"230","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"335","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"343","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"112","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"75","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"16","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"344","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"332","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"214","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"346","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"45","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"200","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"36","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"325","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"82","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"382","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"395","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"28","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"330","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"46","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"78","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"89","target":"80","id":"89-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"94","target":"n_0","id":"94-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"1","id":"n_0-1"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"112","id":"n_0-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"120","id":"n_0-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"121","id":"n_0-121"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"16","id":"n_0-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"17","id":"n_0-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"193","id":"n_0-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"200","id":"n_0-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"202","id":"n_0-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"214","id":"n_0-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"230","id":"n_0-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"240","id":"n_0-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"28","id":"n_0-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"299","id":"n_0-299"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"324","id":"n_0-324"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"325","id":"n_0-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"328","id":"n_0-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"330","id":"n_0-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"332","id":"n_0-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"335","id":"n_0-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"343","id":"n_0-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"344","id":"n_0-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"346","id":"n_0-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"351","id":"n_0-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"36","id":"n_0-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"382","id":"n_0-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"395","id":"n_0-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"45","id":"n_0-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"46","id":"n_0-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"65","id":"n_0-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"66","id":"n_0-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"75","id":"n_0-75"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"78","id":"n_0-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"80","id":"n_0-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"82","id":"n_0-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"88","id":"n_0-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"89","id":"n_0-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"n_0","target":"94","id":"n_0-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"1","target":"n_0","id":"1-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"1","target":"202","id":"1-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"1","target":"65","id":"1-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"112","target":"n_0","id":"112-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"n_0","id":"120-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"112","id":"120-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"121","id":"120-121"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"17","id":"120-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"193","id":"120-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"240","id":"120-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"28","id":"120-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"344","id":"120-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"346","id":"120-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"351","id":"120-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"382","id":"120-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"395","id":"120-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"78","id":"120-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"88","id":"120-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"n_0","id":"121-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"112","id":"121-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"120","id":"121-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"17","id":"121-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"240","id":"121-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"346","id":"121-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"382","id":"121-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"78","id":"121-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"n_0","id":"16-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"214","id":"16-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"230","id":"16-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"330","id":"16-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"343","id":"16-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"66","id":"16-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"75","id":"16-75"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"80","id":"16-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"89","id":"16-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"94","id":"16-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"17","target":"n_0","id":"17-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"17","target":"202","id":"17-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"17","target":"65","id":"17-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"193","target":"n_0","id":"193-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"193","target":"112","id":"193-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"193","target":"82","id":"193-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"n_0","id":"200-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"193","id":"200-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"351","id":"200-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"395","id":"200-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"78","id":"200-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"n_0","id":"202-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"1","id":"202-1"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"17","id":"202-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"395","id":"202-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"45","id":"202-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"66","id":"202-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"80","id":"202-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"94","id":"202-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"214","target":"n_0","id":"214-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"230","target":"n_0","id":"230-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"230","target":"343","id":"230-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"230","target":"80","id":"230-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"240","target":"n_0","id":"240-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"n_0","id":"28-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"112","id":"28-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"120","id":"28-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"121","id":"28-121"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"17","id":"28-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"193","id":"28-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"200","id":"28-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"240","id":"28-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"344","id":"28-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"346","id":"28-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"351","id":"28-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"382","id":"28-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"395","id":"28-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"78","id":"28-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"82","id":"28-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"88","id":"28-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"299","target":"n_0","id":"299-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"n_0","id":"324-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"16","id":"324-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"335","id":"324-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"65","id":"324-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"66","id":"324-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"n_0","id":"325-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"330","id":"325-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"343","id":"325-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"36","id":"325-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"46","id":"325-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"328","target":"n_0","id":"328-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"n_0","id":"330-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"214","id":"330-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"325","id":"330-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"328","id":"330-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"343","id":"330-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"36","id":"330-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"45","id":"330-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"80","id":"330-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"89","id":"330-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"94","id":"330-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"n_0","id":"332-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"335","id":"332-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"36","id":"332-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"45","id":"332-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"46","id":"332-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"66","id":"332-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"n_0","id":"335-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"325","id":"335-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"332","id":"335-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"36","id":"335-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"46","id":"335-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"80","id":"335-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"n_0","id":"343-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"202","id":"343-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"214","id":"343-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"230","id":"343-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"324","id":"343-324"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"325","id":"343-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"36","id":"343-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"45","id":"343-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"46","id":"343-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"65","id":"343-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"66","id":"343-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"75","id":"343-75"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"80","id":"343-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"89","id":"343-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"n_0","id":"344-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"112","id":"344-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"121","id":"344-121"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"17","id":"344-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"193","id":"344-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"240","id":"344-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"28","id":"344-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"346","id":"344-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"351","id":"344-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"382","id":"344-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"395","id":"344-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"78","id":"344-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"82","id":"344-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"88","id":"344-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"346","target":"n_0","id":"346-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"346","target":"120","id":"346-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"346","target":"240","id":"346-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"351","target":"n_0","id":"351-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"n_0","id":"36-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"332","id":"36-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"45","id":"36-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"46","id":"36-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"66","id":"36-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"382","target":"n_0","id":"382-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"n_0","id":"395-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"120","id":"395-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"193","id":"395-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"200","id":"395-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"202","id":"395-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"28","id":"395-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"344","id":"395-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"346","id":"395-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"351","id":"395-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"65","id":"395-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"78","id":"395-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"82","id":"395-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"88","id":"395-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"n_0","id":"45-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"202","id":"45-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"214","id":"45-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"36","id":"45-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"46","id":"45-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"65","id":"45-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"66","id":"45-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"80","id":"45-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"n_0","id":"46-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"325","id":"46-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"332","id":"46-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"343","id":"46-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"36","id":"46-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"45","id":"46-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"66","id":"46-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"80","id":"46-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"n_0","id":"65-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"1","id":"65-1"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"17","id":"65-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"202","id":"65-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"214","id":"65-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"230","id":"65-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"325","id":"65-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"328","id":"65-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"335","id":"65-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"343","id":"65-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"395","id":"65-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"45","id":"65-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"46","id":"65-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"66","id":"65-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"80","id":"65-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"82","id":"65-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"89","id":"65-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"94","id":"65-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"n_0","id":"66-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"16","id":"66-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"202","id":"66-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"214","id":"66-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"230","id":"66-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"324","id":"66-324"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"325","id":"66-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"328","id":"66-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"330","id":"66-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"332","id":"66-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"335","id":"66-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"343","id":"66-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"36","id":"66-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"45","id":"66-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"46","id":"66-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"65","id":"66-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"75","id":"66-75"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"80","id":"66-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"89","id":"66-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"94","id":"66-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"n_0","id":"75-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"16","id":"75-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"230","id":"75-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"324","id":"75-324"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"325","id":"75-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"328","id":"75-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"330","id":"75-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"332","id":"75-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"335","id":"75-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"343","id":"75-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"65","id":"75-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"80","id":"75-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"89","id":"75-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"94","id":"75-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"n_0","id":"78-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"193","id":"78-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"200","id":"78-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"28","id":"78-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"344","id":"78-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"346","id":"78-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"351","id":"78-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"395","id":"78-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"88","id":"78-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"n_0","id":"80-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"16","id":"80-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"214","id":"80-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"230","id":"80-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"325","id":"80-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"330","id":"80-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"332","id":"80-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"343","id":"80-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"36","id":"80-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"45","id":"80-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"46","id":"80-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"65","id":"80-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"66","id":"80-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"89","id":"80-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"82","target":"n_0","id":"82-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"82","target":"193","id":"82-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"82","target":"200","id":"82-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"82","target":"65","id":"82-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"88","target":"n_0","id":"88-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"88","target":"346","id":"88-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"89","target":"n_0","id":"89-n_0"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"89","target":"214","id":"89-214"}}],
  }));


});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/layout-base/layout-base.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cose-base/cose-base.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cose-bilkent@4.1.0/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

See my demo. My real scenario layout is following : (For website constaint, I have deleted about 60000 characters of my data)

[image: my real scenario]

I think the main issues are :

1. The node `n_0` is overlapped by the mass, which is not belong to the compound node.
2. In a large number of edges case, the length between nodes is not ideal.
3. Adding more nodes and edges, the nodes are still huddled together. I think more nodes, more longer distance.

Comment: The problem is definetly your data. You habe an edge from n_0 to every other node and even some back. That is quite unnecessary and builds up a ton of edges. The main goal here should be to decrease the number of edges in my opinion. Second course of action would be to revisit the styling of your nodes/edges. Looking at your data, maybe try switching out cose-blikent to maybe breadthfirst layout? I will post an answer below with the mentioned changes if you'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph below has some differences to yours, namely:

- Removed `n_0`: this node has clustered up the graph with no apparent semantic meaning other than being their root node
- Revisited styles: the pink on pink color-scheme substituted
- Cose-Bilkent layout doesn't work for this: Tried out bfs layout for better results

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),

    ready: function() {
      this.layout({
        name: "breadthfirst"
      }).run();
    },

    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          'content': 'data(id)',
          'text-valign': 'top',
          'text-halign': 'center',
          'background-color': '#2B65EC',
          'color': 'black',
          'width': '30px',
          'height': '30px'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: ":parent",
        style: {
          "background-opacity": 0.3
        }
      },

      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "line-color": "#ad1a66"
        }
      }
    ],

    elements: [{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"202","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"240","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"121","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"89","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"193","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"88","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"328","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"65","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"80","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"66","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"120","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"1","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"351","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"94","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"299","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"17","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"324","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"230","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"335","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"343","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"112","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"75","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"16","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"344","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"332","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"214","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"346","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"45","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"200","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"36","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"325","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"82","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"382","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"395","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"28","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"330","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"46","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"78","parent":"n_2"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"89","target":"80","id":"89-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"1","target":"202","id":"1-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"1","target":"65","id":"1-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"112","id":"120-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"121","id":"120-121"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"17","id":"120-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"193","id":"120-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"240","id":"120-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"28","id":"120-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"344","id":"120-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"346","id":"120-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"351","id":"120-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"382","id":"120-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"395","id":"120-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"78","id":"120-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"120","target":"88","id":"120-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"112","id":"121-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"120","id":"121-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"17","id":"121-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"240","id":"121-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"346","id":"121-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"382","id":"121-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"121","target":"78","id":"121-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"214","id":"16-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"230","id":"16-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"330","id":"16-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"343","id":"16-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"66","id":"16-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"75","id":"16-75"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"80","id":"16-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"89","id":"16-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"16","target":"94","id":"16-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"17","target":"202","id":"17-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"17","target":"65","id":"17-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"193","target":"112","id":"193-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"193","target":"82","id":"193-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"193","id":"200-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"351","id":"200-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"395","id":"200-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"200","target":"78","id":"200-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"1","id":"202-1"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"17","id":"202-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"395","id":"202-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"45","id":"202-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"66","id":"202-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"80","id":"202-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"202","target":"94","id":"202-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"230","target":"343","id":"230-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"230","target":"80","id":"230-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"112","id":"28-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"120","id":"28-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"121","id":"28-121"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"17","id":"28-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"193","id":"28-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"200","id":"28-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"240","id":"28-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"344","id":"28-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"346","id":"28-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"351","id":"28-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"382","id":"28-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"395","id":"28-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"78","id":"28-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"82","id":"28-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"28","target":"88","id":"28-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"16","id":"324-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"335","id":"324-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"65","id":"324-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"324","target":"66","id":"324-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"330","id":"325-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"343","id":"325-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"36","id":"325-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"325","target":"46","id":"325-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"214","id":"330-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"325","id":"330-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"328","id":"330-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"343","id":"330-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"36","id":"330-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"45","id":"330-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"80","id":"330-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"89","id":"330-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"330","target":"94","id":"330-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"335","id":"332-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"36","id":"332-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"45","id":"332-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"46","id":"332-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"332","target":"66","id":"332-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"325","id":"335-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"332","id":"335-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"36","id":"335-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"46","id":"335-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"335","target":"80","id":"335-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"202","id":"343-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"214","id":"343-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"230","id":"343-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"324","id":"343-324"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"325","id":"343-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"36","id":"343-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"45","id":"343-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"46","id":"343-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"65","id":"343-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"66","id":"343-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"75","id":"343-75"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"80","id":"343-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"343","target":"89","id":"343-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"112","id":"344-112"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"121","id":"344-121"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"17","id":"344-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"193","id":"344-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"240","id":"344-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"28","id":"344-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"346","id":"344-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"351","id":"344-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"382","id":"344-382"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"395","id":"344-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"78","id":"344-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"82","id":"344-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"344","target":"88","id":"344-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"346","target":"120","id":"346-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"346","target":"240","id":"346-240"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"332","id":"36-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"45","id":"36-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"46","id":"36-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"36","target":"66","id":"36-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"120","id":"395-120"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"193","id":"395-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"200","id":"395-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"202","id":"395-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"28","id":"395-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"344","id":"395-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"346","id":"395-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"351","id":"395-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"65","id":"395-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"78","id":"395-78"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"82","id":"395-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"395","target":"88","id":"395-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"202","id":"45-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"214","id":"45-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"36","id":"45-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"46","id":"45-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"65","id":"45-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"66","id":"45-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"45","target":"80","id":"45-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"325","id":"46-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"332","id":"46-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"343","id":"46-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"36","id":"46-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"45","id":"46-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"66","id":"46-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"46","target":"80","id":"46-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"1","id":"65-1"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"17","id":"65-17"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"202","id":"65-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"214","id":"65-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"230","id":"65-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"325","id":"65-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"328","id":"65-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"335","id":"65-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"343","id":"65-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"395","id":"65-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"45","id":"65-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"46","id":"65-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"66","id":"65-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"80","id":"65-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"82","id":"65-82"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"89","id":"65-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"65","target":"94","id":"65-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"16","id":"66-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"202","id":"66-202"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"214","id":"66-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"230","id":"66-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"324","id":"66-324"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"325","id":"66-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"328","id":"66-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"330","id":"66-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"332","id":"66-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"335","id":"66-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"343","id":"66-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"36","id":"66-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"45","id":"66-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"46","id":"66-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"65","id":"66-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"75","id":"66-75"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"80","id":"66-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"89","id":"66-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"66","target":"94","id":"66-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"16","id":"75-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"230","id":"75-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"324","id":"75-324"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"325","id":"75-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"328","id":"75-328"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"330","id":"75-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"332","id":"75-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"335","id":"75-335"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"343","id":"75-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"65","id":"75-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"80","id":"75-80"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"89","id":"75-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"75","target":"94","id":"75-94"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"193","id":"78-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"200","id":"78-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"28","id":"78-28"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"344","id":"78-344"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"346","id":"78-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"351","id":"78-351"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"395","id":"78-395"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"78","target":"88","id":"78-88"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"16","id":"80-16"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"214","id":"80-214"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"230","id":"80-230"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"325","id":"80-325"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"330","id":"80-330"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"332","id":"80-332"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"343","id":"80-343"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"36","id":"80-36"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"45","id":"80-45"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"46","id":"80-46"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"65","id":"80-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"66","id":"80-66"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"80","target":"89","id":"80-89"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"82","target":"193","id":"82-193"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"82","target":"200","id":"82-200"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"82","target":"65","id":"82-65"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"88","target":"346","id":"88-346"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"source":"89","target":"214","id":"89-214"}}],
  }));
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 1) n_0 , as a sepecial node, may connect to all other nodes in extreme case. In general business case, it may connect to part of other nodes. According to your meaning, doesn't  ·cose· suit for this case that one nodes connect to too many nodes ?  2）I will learn the `bfs` layout. I need compound and incremental layout features. Does `bfs` support these two features?

Comment: I posted another question about `cose` before with no answer. Could you please shed light on it? Thank you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302671/whats-the-real-meaning-of-randomize-false-using-cose-bilkent-layout

Comment: I actually don't know what the randomize really does, sorry but I can't help there.

Comment: Technically, cose-bilkent is the recommended approach for compound layouts, but this case (many edges and nodes) seemed more fitting to the `bfs` layout. I just started moving the nodes around when I noticed that many edges are acutally not visible in my example. This indicates, that my answer was not the desired output, maybe there are better layouts/options available?

Comment: [Expand-Collapse](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse) could be a nice extension for your code. Please take a look at the demos

Comment: Your suggestions is enough to me. Thank you and I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215789/discussion-between-does-and-stephan-t).